# Swift HKCategorySample

Tags: swift, healthkit

How do I create an `HKCategorySample`? I'm following [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKCategorySample_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/clm/HKCategorySample/categorySampleWithType:value:startDate:endDate:) but it errors with

`Cannot invoke 'init' with an argument list of type '(type: HKCategoryType, value: Int, startDate: NSDate, endDate: NSDate)'`

The docs seem to indicate that those are the correct argument types to pass it, so what is it actually complaining about?

The code I'm using is:

```
let sample = HKCategorySample(
    type: HKCategoryTypeIdentifierSleepAnalysis as HKCategoryType,
    value: HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysis.Asleep as Int,
    startDate: start,
    endDate: end)
```

where both `start` and `end` are `NSDate`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 problems in your code:

1. `HKCategoryTypeIdentifierSleepAnalysis` is just a identifier `String`, you must instantiate it with  [`HKObjectType.categoryTypeForIdentifier()`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/HealthKit/Reference/HKObjectType_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/HKObjectType/categoryTypeForIdentifier:)
2. `HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysis` is `enum`, you cannot cast it to `Int`. To extract `Int` from it, you have to use `.rawValue` property.

Try:

```
let sample = HKCategorySample(
    type: HKObjectType.categoryTypeForIdentifier(HKCategoryTypeIdentifierSleepAnalysis),
    value: HKCategoryValueSleepAnalysis.Asleep.rawValue,
    startDate: start,
    endDate: end
)
```

Comment: This looks like what I need, this is why they should have example usage in the docs. Thanks!

Comment: This works, but it doesn't appear to have been the only source of my error. I wrote in your code, and it kept failing, then I copied mine out and pasted yours in, and it worked, then I swapped them, and it still worked. It seems like the actual error I was getting was unrelated to anything.